# Cygwin: convert: unrecognized option `-d'

Tags: cygwin, pdf-conversion

I use cygwin to convert a pdf file to png. It seems some installation package is missing or there is a problem somewhere

```
D:\>convert -d 300 foo.pdf bar.png
```

> convert: unrecognized option `-d' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1382.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went digging around, and I discovered [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052544/no-images-defined-error-convert-c-convertimagecommand-3212), which was a bit similar to yours.  It, in turn, linked to [this blog post](http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/), which describes using `convert` on the command line as this:

```
convert -density 300 -depth 4 lang.font-name.exp0.pdf lang.font-name.exp0.tif
```

In other words, `-d` may not be a valid option, partly because there are multiple options which begin with the letter `d`.  Try using the following:

```
convert -density 300 foo.pdf bar.png
```

You may have to also specify a `depth` parameter.